90s/early 2000s thriller movie about a crazy man who hijacks a school bus with a dozen or children and a teacher
US made movie. Unsure whether it was for theater or a TV movie. 
Story Points:

As mentioned in the title, a school bus containing a dozen or so children and a teacher (female) is hijacked by a crazy man and are held hostage. I think the crazy man had medium long black hair. 
During the climax, The police surround the bus and shoot the crazy man. One of the children, a boy, suffers a minor eye injury from shards of the bus window, but is stated by medics to be alright.
The swat has a few officers escort the children as the bus is finally driving them back to their homes.


Possibly Sudden Terror: The Hijacking of School Bus #17 (1996 TV Movie)

A crazed lunatic takes over a school bus filled with special needs children, threatening to blow it up if his demands are not met.

Unfortunately, IMDB is acting up on me, so I can't check many of the details, but an article about the real-life incident that inspired the movie says that the hijacker was killed by a police sniper.
Some clips on Youtube:




This is the movie ^^ Thank you very much !

You're welcome. I just searched for school bus hijacking movies. :) At first I thought it was going to be related to "Where Have They Taken Our Children?"
